# AJAX isn't working on mobile, but it is on Chrome developer tool

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, jquery-mobile

I'm working on a clients website and I'm running into this issue where my AJAX call isn't working on a specific page on the mobile of my site.
[Page having issues.](http://store.arsnet.com/storefrontCommerce/itemDetail.do?item-id=1948&order-quantity=1&item-index=0&customer-item=19571&order-uom=EACH&warehouse-id=1&item-number=19571)
It seems that the header and footer are only having issues when on a mobile phone itself. It looks fine in the Chrome developer tools however.
I can't reproduce this on my browser, so I am not sure how to diagnose the issue. Any advice would be greatly appreciated! You can get to this page by going to http://store.arsnet.com/ then clicking on a category, then a specific category, then a product.

Thanks. If you need any additional information please don't hesitate to ask.

Here's the specific AJAX Call:

```
$.ajax({
     url : "/arsweb/DONOTDELETE",
    dataType: "html",
    success : function (data) {
        var html = $.parseHTML(data);
        //alert("working");
        $("div#search").prependTo($("#centerMainColumnPadding"))

        $("#HeaderOnePaddingWrap").html( $(html).find( 'div.skin_width.clearafter:eq(0)' ).html());
        $("#HeaderOnePaddingWrap").append('<div style="clear:both"></div>');
        //alert($(html).find( 'section#skin_header' ).html())
        //alert($("#siteHeadmiddle").html());
        $("#siteHeadmiddle").before('<div id="sf_nav"></div>');
        $("#sf_nav").html( $(html).find( 'section#skin_header' ).html());


        $("span#dnn_arsheader_dnnSEARCH_ClassicSearch").parent().hide();

        $("div#search").prependTo($("#searchcontainer"));


        $("#arssocialmedia").insertAfter($("#standardMenu"));
        $(".menu_box").css({"width":"100%","padding-bottom":"10px"});

        $("#siteFootouter").html( $(html).find('footer.footer_bg').html());

        $(".bottomRightHeader").prependTo($('.icons_menu'));

        $(".wp_newCart").insertAfter($('#userAccountInfo'));

        //$("#centercart").appendTo("#skin_topLeft");


        $("#arssocialmedia").find("img[alt^='Linked']").attr("src","wp/ars/linkedinicon.png");
        $("#arssocialmedia").find("img[alt^='Facebook']").attr("src","wp/ars/facebookicon.png");
        $("#arssocialmedia").find("img[alt^='Google']").attr("src","wp/ars/googleplusicon.png");
        $(".mobile_nav").find("img[alt^='Menu']").attr("src","wp/ars/btn_menu.png");
        $(".site_logo").find("img[alt^='American']").attr("src","wp/ars/arslogo.png");

        $(".mobile_nav").click(function(){
                    $("#standardMenu").slideToggle("fast");
        });




        checkSize();
        $(window).resize(checkSize);


        function checkSize(){
            if ($("#wp_checkout").css("float") == "none" ){
                $("#standardMenu").hide();
                $(".menu_box").css("width","100%");
                $("#arssocialmedia").wrap('<div id="m_nav_wp"></div>');
                $(".mobile_nav").prependTo($("#m_nav_wp"));
                $("#m_nav_wp").css("padding-bottom","5px").append("<div style='clear:both;'></div>");
                //$("#m_nav_wp").insertBefore("#StandardMenu");

                $(".subMenu").find("span").addClass("navhover");
                $(".subMenu").find("li").addClass("navhover");
                   $("td.label").css("color","black;");

                   $("#m_nav_wp").insertBefore($('.menu_box'))


                 var numCartItems = ($("#numberOfCartItems").text())

                if (numCartItems == 0) {

                    $("#displayCheckout").css("color","#CCC");

                } 


                $("#searchcontainer").wrap('<div style="clear:both; width:100%; text-align:center;" id="searchcontainer_wrap"></div>');
                $("#searchcontainer_wrap").append('<div style="clear:both;"></div>')
                //$("#searchcontainer").css("float","none");
                //$("#searchcontainer").css("margin","0 auto !important");                  

            }



        }




        var config = {
        sensitivity: 2,
        interval:110,
        over: HoverOver,
        timeout:110,
        out: HoverOut
        };
        var configsub = {
        sensitivity: 2,
        interval:110,
        over: HoverOversub,
        timeout:110,
        out: HoverOutsub
        };
        var configsubsub = {
        sensitivity: 2,
        interval:110,
        over: HoverOversubsub,
        timeout:110,
        out: HoverOutsubsub
        };

        if ($(window).width() >= 992){
            $("#standardMenu .rootMenu > li.haschild").hoverIntent(config);
            $("#standardMenu .subMenu li.haschild").hoverIntent(configsub);
            $("#standardMenu .subMenu li li.haschild").hoverIntent(configsubsub);       
        }else if ($(window).width() < 992){
            $("#standardMenu .rootMenu > li").each(function(i){
                var i = i + 1;
                $("#standardMenu li.child-"+i+" .navarrow").click(function(event) {
                  event.preventDefault();
                  $("#standardMenu li.child-"+i+" .subMenu").slideToggle(100);
                  $(this).toggleClass("navarrow2"); return false;
                }); 
            });
        }

       // For Win8 Tablet
       $('#standardMenu .haschild li').attr("aria-haspopup","false");
       $('#standardMenu .haschild li').attr("role","menu");
       $('#standardMenu .haschild').attr("aria-haspopup","true");
       $('#standardMenu .haschild').attr("role","menuitem");

    },error : function (a,b,c) {
        console.log(arguments);

    }

});
```

Comment: Are you seeing any errors on mobile? You can try using Chrome developer tools and emulate a mobile phone to see any errors and might also be helpful in debugging your issues.

Comment: What part of the page is using AJAX? What code is making the AJAX call? Are you getting any specific errors? "not working" is not enough to go on.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging => check out this page to see the errors you're getting on the phone's browser or even app (webview) environment.

Comment: The header is where it is receiving the error I believe. The ajax call is in wp_Footer.jsp

Comment: I'm not receiving any errors in the chrome developer tool because I can't produce the issue on Chrome, only on a physical device.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the issue using Safari developer tools.
I found that there was a syntax error in my jQuery.

This is odd, because I made sure the other browsers were not cached.
So I suppose I'll add Safari to my list of useful developer tools.